# Marking FB page posts as spam

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, spam, facebook-wall

How can I mark posts as spam on my wall or the page's wall, which I manage using my application? I have `read_stream`, `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions. I've tried to google it and to search in FB documentation, but found nothing.

**update**

Can I later un-spam that post via API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant update a post, you just can delete it via api. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ for more info.

Comment: no I don't want to delete it, in my application I have delete button also, that actually do that and I need spam button that will mark post as spam

Comment: mark it as spam is updating, and as i said, its not supported via api.